# Upload file with ajax call in django

Tags: python, ajax, django, upload

I created form upload file in django. it is working. But when i try with ajax in django file upload is not working.

My code:

models.py

```
class Upload(models.Model):
   documents = models.FileField(upload_to=content_file_name)
   user = models.ForeignKey(User)

class Meta:
    app_label = 'documentapp'
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
class UploadForm(forms.Form):
    documents = forms.FileField()
```

html:

```
<input type="file" name="documents" id="documents" class="form-control" required="required""/>
 <input type="button" id="upload_file_button" required="required" value="Upload" onclick="UploadUserDocuments()"/>
```

ajax in same html file:

```
function UploadUserDocuments() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/signup/upload/",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
           documents:$('education_documents').val(),     
        },
        success: function(response){
        }
    });
}
```

view.py

```
def upload(request):
context = RequestContext(request)
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])
    return HttpResponse('true')
else:
    return HttpResponse('GET')
```

handle_uplaoded_fiel.py

```
def handle_uploaded_file(f):
with open('some/file/name.txt', 'wb+') as destination:
    for chunk in f.chunks():
        destination.write(chunk)
```

Comment: why dont you use forms.ModelForm instead forms.Form?

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with the HTML/JS.

- The first line of your HTML has a double terminating quotation for the value of the `required` attribute.
- Your UploadUserDocuments() function does the following:

  ```
  $('education_documents').val()
  ```

  which is attempting to match an element such as `<education_documents>` rather than the usual way of selecting the value of an element by its id (i.e. using the # selector).

However, it's more involved to perform a file upload using JQuery.  This answer has some ideas: [How can I upload files asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't send csrf_token. You can skip it for you view(which is not really recommended) by using [csrf_exempt](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt) decorator.

Otherwise you should add {%csrf_token%} tag to your template. It will create hidden field with CSRF token. The way how to handle it in AJAX you can find in [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/#ajax).

Also I'm curious why don't you render form from variable, but add HTML manually instead - but it isn't directly related to the topic.

So I'd to do it like:
html:

```
<form id="upload_doc" action="/signup/upload/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> {% csrf_token %} 
   {{form}}
   <input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

Also please see notices from @Ben Rowland answer

Comment: <form  id="upload_doc" action="/signup/upload/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
               {% csrf_token %}

Comment: thanks fro the reply. i did csrf token. My doubt in Form.py, because i don't know how to use form. becuase 'if form.is_valid' condition is false

Comment: try to print form errors(form.errors) in template and say what it say to you, or print it after is_valid() statement in Python(or see it with debugger if you use it)

Comment: this is 'print form' in log                    =================================
<tr><th><label for="id_education_documents">Education documents:</label></th><td><ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul><input id="id_documents" name="documents" type="file" /></td></tr>